# DTD file for XML - declaring ATTLIST with multiple IDREF values

Tags: xml, dtd

I am writing a DTD file, and need an entity to have an atribute that is an IDREF, it can contain multiple values in that attribute e.g  when a, b, c are ID's of other human instances.

I read [this](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/DTD/Structure/ATTLIST.aspx) about formatting the ATTLIST in the DTD file and did not find there, or anywhere a solution to my perticular case. I found how to allow multiple friend tags within the object like so in the xml

```
<human> 
<friend/> 
<friend/> 
</human>
```

But this does not fit my needs.

I tried using

```
<!ELEMENT human> 
<!ATTLIST friends IDREF>
```

But it does not fit my needs of multiple friends in that attribute. 
Is it at all possible? How can I declare it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The IDREFS attribute type appears to do what you need, if I have understood your requirement correctly.

Comment: Thanks, could you give an example for the DTD and XML?

Comment: You can search for an example as easily as I can.

Comment: I don't care two hoots whether you accept my answer or not. I'm here to help, not to earn brownie points.

Comment: @Micheal Kay, appreciate the help, would like to respect it with accepting the answer, I was not suggesting you helped for the reputation points, just following the house rules...